# Cloudformation - S3 AWS event not being triggered?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, aws-event-bridge

I am trying to make a cloudformation stack that watches an S3 bucket (created by a different stack) and kicks off a codebuild run when a certain file is uploaded/overwritten. My template looks something like:

```
  NgBuildCodeBuild:
    Type: AWS::CodeBuild::Project
    ...
   
  AmazonCloudWatchEventRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - events.amazonaws.com
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
      Path: /
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: !Sub
            - 'myapp-frontend-built-${Branch}-watch-s3'
            - { Branch: !Ref TrackedBranch }
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: 2012-10-17
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action: codebuild:StartBuild
                Resource: !GetAtt NgBuildCodeBuild.Arn

  AmazonCloudWatchEventRule:
    Type: AWS::Events::Rule
    Properties:
      EventPattern:
        source:
          - aws.s3
        detail-type:
          - 'AWS API Call via CloudTrail'
        detail:
          eventSource:
            - s3.amazonaws.com
          eventName:
            - PutObject
            - CompleteMultipartUpload
          requestParameters:
            bucketName:
              - 'my-app-src-s3-bucket'
            key:
              - !Sub
                - 'myGitUsername/myRepoName/${Branch}/src.zip'
                - { Branch: !Ref TrackedBranch }
      Targets:
        - Arn: !GetAtt NgBuildCodeBuild.Arn
          RoleArn: !GetAtt AmazonCloudWatchEventRole.Arn
          Id: codebuild-myapp-frontend
```

The stack deploys fine, but when I upload a `src.zip` to the key/destination being watched (`'myGitUsername/myRepoName/${Branch}`)...nothing happens. I am pretty sure I am uploading to the correct S3 bucket and path. It looks like the event was never triggered. When I look at the metrics for the deployed rule in event bridge, there is no data. I was expecting this aws CLI command to trigger the event:
`aws s3 cp $outputbucketkey s3://$outputbucket/$outputbucketpath`. Deleting `src.zip` and re-uploading it using a web browser also does not trigger the event.

Am I using the wrong eventNames? Or have I misunderstood what event bridge is used for?

Comment: Include `CopyObject` in `eventName`? Also, make sure the key you've specified matches.

Comment: Have you enabled S3 data events in your CloudTrial trial?

Comment: @Marcin no. That was the issue thanks. Event rules started being triggered and kicking off the build once I made that. Could you show how to do that in cloudformation? I made the cloudtrail in the web console but ideally it would be part of this cloudformation template.

Comment: No problem. Glad it works. I provided an answer based on the comments. I don't have full example of cloudtrial for your use-case. I would recommend attempting to create it yourself, and if have difficulties, make new question with relevant details tailored to your requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was caused by the **missing trail** in CloudTrial. To log S3 put events, a trail must be created with [data events for S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/logging-data-events-with-cloudtrail.html#logging-data-events-examples). To enable the trial in CloudWatch, [AWS::CloudTrail::Trail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cloudtrail-trail.html#aws-resource-cloudtrail-trail--examples) with [AWS::CloudTrail::Trail DataResource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cloudtrail-trail-dataresource.html).